# Haskell SQLite-Simple user-generated query

Tags: database, sqlite, haskell, sqlite-simple

With the code below I get an error on the number of arguments, although the documentation says it should be exactly so:

```
extractData :: IO ()
extractData = do
  userToolIDSelect <- getLine
  connection <- open "tools.db"
  resp <- query_ connection "SELECT * FROM tools WHERE toolID = (?)" (Only userToolIDSelect) :: IO [Tool]
  mapM_ print resp
```

But if I modify the code to have a fixed ID parameter like so: 
`resp <- query_ connection "SELECT * FROM tools WHERE toolID = 1;" :: IO [Tool]` it works fine.

Any idea what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`query_` function doesn't perform substitution. Replace it with the `query` function and it should work.

Relevant docs: https://www.stackage.org/haddock/lts-12.18/sqlite-simple-0.4.16.0/Database-SQLite-Simple.html#v:query_

Comment: You sir, are brilliant! Thanks so much!